# Simulate a laptop behind a proxy server

Tags: java, networking, proxy

I wrote a small java code that uploads a file to an ftp server.
It's not working for people behind a proxy server, to debug, I'd like to simulate their conditions.
What's the best way to do it? is there a proxy server I can download and setup so that my computer requires proxy setup to access the network?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Squid for Windows](http://www.acmeconsulting.it/SquidNT.html), which is a very good proxy, but maybe the smaller [CC Proxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/) is enough for your needs.

Comment: The link to [Squid for Windows](http://www.acmeconsulting.it/SquidNT.html) is broken here.

Comment: @AndersonGreen After more than 10 years I think there are better solutions out somewhere